# spring-boot-starter-aop only available for open source projects

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, licensing

I've just encountered an issue regarding licensing with `spring-boot-starter-aop`.
`spring-boot-starter-aop` comes with a non-optional compile transitive dependency to `aspectjweaver`.

`aspectjweaver` though is licensed under EPL 1.0 which as far as I understand requires any project using it to have its source code made public. Since we're developing a commercial product we cannot make the code public.

Does that mean that Spring AOP can only be used for open source projects? Or is this a problem only if I add the dependency through Spring Boot Starter. Is there any other way to use Spring AOP without `aspectjweaver`?

Moreover, other Spring Boot Starters have a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-aop` like `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` (for some reason). But in this case I was able to exclude just the `aspectjweaver` dependency so there would be no licensing infringements and apparently the project still works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPL does not prevent you from building closed proprietary software using EPL licensed libraries.

You don't need to worry - there are thousands of closed source projects built on the top of Spring AOP.

Comment: Thank you! In that case it seems I was misinformed with regards to the EPL licensing.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/174907/can-i-use-epl-licensed-libraries-and-not-give-out-the-source-code-of-my-applicat